# Intent Redirection Vulnerability in play console

Tags: flutter, intentfilter

got the below error when uploaded my flutter application into play store:

Intent Redirection

Your app contains an intent redirection vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details.

```
c.b.a.a$b->onReceive
```

what do i have to resolve it?

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en

Comment: Hi @Agan Dev, do you find any solutions to this. We are also facing this and it's really difficult to pin point the issue from flutter side.

Answer (score 0):

Intent Redirection Vulnerability triggering intent injection and redirection attacks resulting in leaking private data stored by the app.

Ensure that the extracted Intent is from a trustworthy source.
You can verify that the originating Activity can be trusted using methods like "getCallingActivity" method.